# CheckedListBox items to TextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, checkedlistbox

I want to get all checked items from CheckedListBox1 to TextBox1.

So far i tried:

```
TextBox1.Text = CheckedListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray
```

not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: why this is tagged to c#

Comment: Maybe someone who knows C# can write answer and i could try to translate it to vb.net?

Comment: You could try `TextBox1.Text = string.Join(",", CheckedListBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToList());`. I like one liners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox1.Text` is a `String`, and you're going to assign a `String[]` to a `String`. It's totally nonsense. Try to assign to `TextBox1.Lines`.

**Update - Try this**

```
TextBox1.Lines = CheckedListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray
```

Comment: Just one more question; How can i show those items in MsgBox? I tried `MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)`, replaced `Text` with `Lines`, replaced `Lines` with `Lines.ToString()`, still not working. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Easy, why don't you just get it from `TextBox1.Text`?

Comment: It shows blank message box :/
Edit: So when i try MsgBox in same form as TextBox1, it shows its text, yet if i try MsgBox in other forms it shows blank MsgBox. Is this error in my code or i'm missing something? lol

Comment: You do `TextBox1.Lines = CheckedListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray()` first, so you can get the `TextBox1.Text` for the message box. If you want to do the same in other form, or you don't need the textbox anymore, please consider @muffi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
    For Each clb As String In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        textbox1.AppendText(clb & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works too. Sorry, i had small error in code so it didn't appeared lol...Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

C# (Question originally had C# tag)

```
CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection items = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;

foreach (string item in items) {
    textBox1.Text += item;
}
```